# Facet wrap plots with nested `ggforce::facet_zoom`

Tags: r, ggplot2, ggforce

I'd like to make a plot with `ggplot2::facet_wrap` or `facet_grid` with nested plots that use `ggforce::facet_zoom`.

I'd also be happy enough lining them up in a similar fashion to `facet_grid`, preferably with the strip text labels, though also can't quite see a way to get that to work either.

E.g. a faceted plot

```r
library(ggplot2)
library(ggforce)
library(dplyr)

p1 <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x = factor(gear),
      y = mpg,
      fill = factor(gear)
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(
    facets = ~cyl,
    nrow = 2,
    scales = "free_y"
  )

p1
```

[image]

But each facet should be like this (this is the first facet above):

```r
zoomlims <- data.frame(
  cyl = c(4, 6, 8),
  lower = c(27, 18, 13),
  upper =c(32, 21, 17)
)

p2a <- ggplot(mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 4)) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x = factor(gear),
      y = mpg,
      fill = factor(gear)
    )
  ) +
  facet_zoom(
    ylim = c(zoomlims$lower[1], zoomlims$upper[1]),
    zoom.size = 1
  )

p2a
```

[image]

Ideally one facet call would take all the arguments to both zoom and wrap, but they won't, and calling one facet function after the other just overrides the previous one, e.g. zoom second

```r
p3a <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x = factor(gear),
      y = mpg,
      fill = factor(gear)
    )
  ) +
  facet_wrap(
    facets = ~cyl,
    nrow = 2,
    scales = "free_y"
  ) +
  facet_zoom(
    ylim = c(zoomlims$lower, zoomlims$upper),
    zoom.size = 1
  )

p3a
```

[image]

Or wrap second

```r
p3b <- ggplot(mtcars) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x = factor(gear),
      y = mpg,
      fill = factor(gear)
    )
  ) +
  facet_zoom(
    ylim = c(zoomlims$lower, zoomlims$upper),
    zoom.size = 1
  ) +
  facet_wrap(
    facets = ~cyl,
    nrow = 2,
    scales = "free_y"
  )

p3b
```

[image]

It might be possible to mimic this with patchwork, [but that doesn't work either](https://github.com/thomasp85/patchwork/issues/149), and wouldn't include the strip text from wrapping (though could annotate).

```r
library(patchwork)
p2b <- ggplot(mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 6)) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x = factor(gear),
      y = mpg,
      fill = factor(gear)
    )
  ) +
  facet_zoom(
    ylim = c(zoomlims$lower[1], zoomlims$upper[1]),
    zoom.size = 1
  )

p2c <- ggplot(mtcars %>% filter(cyl == 8)) +
  geom_boxplot(
    aes(
      x = factor(gear),
      y = mpg,
      fill = factor(gear)
    )
  ) +
  facet_zoom(
    ylim = c(zoomlims$lower[1], zoomlims$upper[1]),
    zoom.size = 1
  )


p4 <- p2a + p2b + p2c + plot_layout(nrow = 2, guides = "collect")

p4
```

[image]

Thoughts?

<sup>Created on 2020-02-14 by the [reprex package](https://reprex.tidyverse.org) (v0.3.0)</sup>

Comment: Does cowplot have the same problem as patchwork?

Comment: Does `plot(gridExtra::arrangeGrob(p2a, p2b, p2c))` bring you any closer to what you want? It is very hacky ...

Comment: @Bas for me it works perfectly ;)

Answer (score 0):

I think the new version of `ggforce` fixes this problem
Just install the new version with `devtools::install_github("thomasp85/ggforce")`

Release text:
https://github.com/thomasp85/ggforce/releases/tag/v0.4.0